# Adding Days to input

Tags: python-3.x

I looking to make a program in python that contains the days of the week so people can input the data needed on those days.

eg.
Please enter number for Monday:

```
Please enter number for Tuesday:
```

Is there a way to automatically change the day so you don't have to type each question in each time?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code?

Comment: Are you want to make a time-table of a person on that day. And it will update as the days changes

Comment: Basically I need to have the program ask the user to enter a number on each day of the week.  Is there a function that when a number is entered on Monday for example that the next question will be please enter a number for Tuesday,  The Please enter a number for Wednesday etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below lines of code can help you input data while iterating over a list. Add the logic in do something part of the code snippet to get and set the data.

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday, "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    for day in days:
        inp = input("Please enter number for {}".format(day))
        <do something>
```

Comment: Glad I could help... Does this solve your issue? Please accept if it does.